# inequality of a continous function for which $f(a)=f(b)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ a twice diferrentiable function with its derivate continous and $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Prove that
$$2\int^b_a (f'(x))^2\,dx\le\int^b_a (f(x))^2\,dx +\int^b_a (f''(x))^2\,dx$$
The only idea that I have is to separate de parts maybe like this
$$\int^b_a (f'(x))^2\,dx-\int^b_a (f(x))^2\,dx\le \int^b_a (f"(x))^2\,dx-\int^b_a (f'(x))^2\,dx$$ but from I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 4):

First integrate $\displaystyle \int_a^b f'(x) f'(x)\, dx$ by parts. Then apply an inequality of the form $ab \le \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!